# Access folder throughout Xamarin app

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, uwp, folder-permissions

Is there any folder that can be accessed through a Xamarin.Forms app? The app will be deployed to Android, iOS and as a UWP app. I have a database file and so far, I am using SpecialFolders.Personal, which works for Android and iOS, but not UWP. I would need to get permission for this folder in Windows.

So is there any folder I can use across all 3 devices for which I don't need any special permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms has provided `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` enum that use to get universal storage path. And it need to be combined with `Environment.GetFolderPath` method.

```
var ApplicationDataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

For more please refer [**File Handling in Xamarin.Forms**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=vswin#saving-and-loading-files)

Comment: Can I embed a resource in there when launching my application (ie drag and drop it in)

Comment: @jamesfdearborn, No, you could do this, because the app run in sandbox, adding files to the sandbox folder manually is not safe.